# Cardinality of $X \cup Y$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are two sets $X$ and $Y$, where $|X| = 20$ and $|Y| = 32$. Which one of the following is a possible cardinality of $X \cup Y $?

A. $5$

B. $10$

C. $24$

D. $40$

Correct answer was C, $|X \cup Y | = 24$, which i don't understand. Can anyone clear up this question?

Comment: That answer is incorrect: the correct answer is D, $40$.

Comment: It must be at least 32 (X is subset of Y) and at must 52 (X and Y are completely disjoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer must be D. Because we know that $A ,B \subseteq A \cup B$, therefore the cardinality of $A \cup B$ must be larger than or equal to $\max(20,32) =32$. The only choice compatible with this is 40.

Comment: yours answer certainly makes more sense to me now..Thank you ,just one more doubt. What would be the Cardinality of Exclusive OR |X⊕Y| ?

Comment: The cardinality of $X\oplus Y$ is between $0$ and $|X| + |Y|$, inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, $X \subseteq X \cup Y$ and $Y \subseteq X \cup Y$, so $$|X \cup Y| \ge |X| \text{ and } |X \cup Y| \ge |Y|,$$ which implies the only possible answer is (D).

Answer (score 0):

For finite sets $X$ and $Y$ we have the formula $|X\cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X\cap Y|$.  This means we can rule out three of the options right away (why?).  What is left?